# Android Best way to convert byte array to Bitmap?

Tags: java, android, byte

I know why OutOfMemoryError Exception occurs.But there are any best way to convert byte array to Bitmap.And I used below code ,But when large byte it force close app and gives OutOfMemoryError Exception.

And i have API it just return me byte array nothing else.

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytearray, 0, bytearray.length);
```

Comment: How big is the bytearray? Is really a big image? Perhaps the image is really big for the phone memory and you should compress it on the server-side if you are retrieving it from there.

Comment: checkout this nice explanation http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 9):

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapbytes , 0, bitmapbytes .length);
```

Returns The decoded bitmap, or null if the image could not be decode.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what worked for me:
photo is a string of an image by the way.

```
byte[] imgbytes = Base64.decode(photo, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgbytes, 0,
imgbytes.length);
imageupload.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to use this following method ([DOC](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options%29), same method, but with the options parameter):

```
public static Bitmap decodeByteArray (byte[] data, int offset, int length, BitmapFactory.Options opts)
```

And play with the [options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html) parameter. Hope this will help you =)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the AQuery library to load your images, this will help you resize, view etc and avoid the most common memory leaks. This tool can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/android-query/

Comment: How could convert byte[] to bitmap with AQuery?