# How can play streaming Video from frame byte array

Tags: java, android, video-streaming

Thanks for watching of question and sorry about my english XD

(use Android Studio with JAVA) 
How can i play streaming video from byte array to VideoView or MediaPlayer,
i have received byte array from ZeroMQ socket, and byte array content is Frame(size w: 640 h: 360 base64 encoding)

ZeroMQ protocol thread code

```
public class ZeromQMessageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
            try{
                ZMQ.Context context = ZMQ.context(1);
                ZMQ.Socket socket = context.socket(ZMQ.SUB);
                socket.subscribe(ZMQ.SUBSCRIPTION_ALL);
                socket.connect("tcp://192.168.0.21:8080");
                socket.setReceiveTimeOut(5000);


                int count = 0;
                while (count < 10000){
                    byte[] datas = socket.recv(0);
                    count ++;
                }
                Log.e("socket closed: " , ""+count);

                socket.close();
                context.term();

            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("socket error: " , e.getLocalizedMessage());
                Log.e("socket error: " , e.toString());
            }
            return "test";
        }
    }
```

Server code (for refer) ps.maybe python code?

```
context = zmq.Context()
footage_socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
footage_socket.bind('tcp://*:{}'.format(PORT))

while True:
  try:
       for frame in frames:
           encoded, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
           jpg_astext = base64.b64encode(buffer)
           footage_socket.send(jpg_as_text)

  except Exception as e: ...
```

Comment: You can convert byte array to bitmap and keep setting bitmap to image view continuously in the loop to see video streaming.

Comment: @santosh kumar  Thank you sir for comment, firstly need base64 decoding process and convert bitmap right?

byte [] base64 -> decode byte[] -> bitmap -> video

Comment: Yes correct. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547327/android-best-way-to-convert-byte-array-to-bitmap/11879370